# I need help figuring out what is wrong with my code

Tags: java, error-handling

I'm getting some errors saying that it cannot find symbol

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ShippingSales
{
    public static void main (String [] args)

{
    int weight,  miles;
    String temp;
    double shippingcharge, rate;

    shippingcharge = miles * rate;
    miles = 500;

    temp = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the weight of the package");
    weight = Interger.parseInt(temp);

    if (weight <= 2)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total amount is " + shipppingcharge);
        rate = 1.10;
    }

    if (weight > 2 && weight<= 6 )
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total amount is " + shipppingcharge);
        rate = 2.20;
    }

    if (weight > 6 && weight<= 10)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total amount is " + shipppingcharge);
        rate = 3.70;
    }

    if (weight > 10)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total amount is " + shipppingcharge);
        rate = 3.80;
    }

}


}
```

Comment: Which symbols? if the compiler say `shipppingcharge` cannot be found. You just have to check you spell it right - which is not the case. Same thing for `Interger`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Interger.parseInt(temp);
```

Anything wrong with this line you can see at second glance?

Hint: Spelling.

Also, you misspelled "shipping charge" in a variable reference multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Well you used three "p"s in all of the showMessageDialogs but the variable is called `shippingcharge`

And you spelled `Integer` wrong, you used `Interger`